# Manage Windows and linux programs with a Linux (WSL) window manager

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, window-manager, xming

Im wanting to run a fullscreen Xming (or alternative) instance within Windows with a custom window manager (Using i3wm) to replace the pesky windows Shell.  This will give me native Linux and Windows support with my chosen WM without having to use Wine.

I can setup what I describe only for Linux applications, starting any windows gui applications opens above and out of the Xming window, being managed by Windows.

Ive tried using Xpra as a server on Windows, but the support isn't there.  Im not sure where to even start looking to solve this.

---

If there is any solution, how do I manage/render/control Windows apps from within a Xming(or alternative) instance?

Comment: It's not possible. If you want to use full i3wm desktop environment (DE) why don't you just install a GNU/Linux distribution with that DE?

Comment: @Biswapriyo I want to have native Windows support.  Wine is good, but it isn't as good as Windows itself.

Comment: WSL is a "subsystem" which is not a replacement of Windows shell, an integral part of Windows ecosystem. As a workaround the X Server (here Xming) can be run automatically after startup with `-fullscreen` option. If WSL replaces Windows, MS would not invent it :)